# How can I customize each axis in a subplot with subplot2grid?

Tags: python, axis, date-formatting, subplot

I'm running some tests with a csv file I made up, with the following code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import dates as mpl_dates

data = pd.read_csv('teste_csvread_panda.csv')
data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date'])
data.sort_values('date', inplace=True)
date = data['date']
temp = data['temp']
sal = data['sal']

ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((2,1), (0,0), rowspan=1, colspan=1)
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((2,1), (1,0), rowspan=1, colspan=1)

ax1.plot(date,temp, marker='.', label='temp')
ax1.legend(loc='upper right')
date_format = mpl_dates.DateFormatter('%b %d')
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(date_format)

ax2.plot(date,sal, marker='.', label='sal')
ax2.legend(loc='lower left')
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(date_format)

plt.show()
```

resulting plot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QH7sX.png).

I would like to format the date axis for both subplots, but clearly it's working only for the last subplot. How can I make this happen?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. You need to define which axis is the current axis. I used `plt.sca(ax)` to do that at the beginning of each plot.

```py
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((2,1), (0,0), rowspan=1, colspan=1)
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((2,1), (1,0), rowspan=1, colspan=1)

plt.sca(ax1)
plt.plot(date,temp, marker='.', label='temp')
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
date_format = mpl_dates.DateFormatter('%b %d')
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(date_format)

plt.sca(ax2)
plt.plot(date, sal, marker='.', label='sal')
plt.legend(loc='lower left')
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(date_format)

plt.show()
```

Comment: @ThiagoCaminha Could you please **`accept`** and `upvote` the answer? Thank you.